# Inner join single column using Eloquent

Tags: php, orm, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to get a *single column* of an inner joined model.

```
$items = Item::with('brand')->get();
```

This gives me the whole `brand` object as well, but I only want `brand.brand_name`

```
$items = Item::with('brand.brand_name')->get();
```

Didn´t work for me.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do you always only want brand_name .. or do you only in this instance want the object to only contain 'brand_name' ?

Comment: just for completeness' sake: eager loading (using `with`) does not use joins, but `WHERE IN` queries. the latter do scale very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get related models (another query) with just the column you want (an id, see below):

```
$items = Item::with(['brand' => function ($q) {
   $q->select('id','brand_name'); // id is required always to match relations
                                  // it it was hasMany/hasOne also parent_id would be required
}])->get();
// return collection of Item models and related Brand models. 
// You can call $item->brand->brand_name on each model
```

On the other hand you can simply join what you need:

```
$items = Item::join('brands', 'brands.id', '=', 'items.brand_id')
   ->get(['items.*','brands.brand_name']);
// returns collection of Item models, each having $item->brand_name property added.
```

I'm guessing `Item` belongsTo `Brand`, table names are `items` and `brands`. If not, edit those values accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $items = Item::with(array('brand'=>function($query){
          $query->select('name');
  }))->get();
```